# CoordinatorLayout with RecyclerView: onScroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a RecyclerView where I have added different actions that can be performed on the list items. Particularly, `DragDrop` and `SwipeDismiss`. `DragDrop` is initiated by long-press, and `SwipeDismiss` is initiated by swiping. I have to watch for scroll events to block those actions from happening. It is annoying to be scrolling then it suddenly switched to dragging. Before I would add an `OnScrollListener` to handle this.

**This is what I did before:**

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
    if(newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
        drag.setCurrentAction(IDLE);
    } else {
        drag.setCurrentAction(SCROLL);
    }
}
```

---

**No longer will work**

I recently added [CoordinatorLayout for collapsable toolbars](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html). Now when scrolling up, `drag` wont get set to `SCROLL` until the toolbar has been collapsed. I tried to create my own behavior, but that would replace my current behavior I am using; `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`. This removed the behaviors I wanted for the toolbar and didn't work to notify my `drag` state.

---

**What I have tried:**

```
@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout cl, CollapsingToolbarLayout child, View directTargetChild,
        View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {

    if (nestedScrollAxes == ViewCompat.SCROLL_AXIS_VERTICAL) {
        if (drag.getCurrentAction().ordinal() < SCROLL.ordinal()) {
            /* No actions have started and we are scrolling. set the new action */
            drag.setCurrentAction(SCROLL);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onStartNestedScroll(cl, child, directTargetChild, target, nestedScrollAxes);
}

@Override
public void onStopNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, CollapsingToolbarLayout child, View target) {
    super.onStopNestedScroll(coordinatorLayout, child, target);
    if (drag.getCurrentAction() == SCROLL) {
        drag.setCurrentAction(INVALID);
    }
}
```

**So my question**

How do I listen for those scroll changes on my recycler view that are being intercepted by the `CoordinatorLayout`? Is a Behavior the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add a touchEvent listener, then deactivate the interceptors events for the parent viewgroup holder? I reckon that returns to the child the control of any touch event you want to handle.

```
    scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
               // Disallow the touch request for parent scroll on touch of child view

                     v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                      v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
               }
          return false;
          }
       });
```

Answer (score -1):

You should instead use [ItemTouchHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html) as detailed in [this blog post](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf).

It contains methods such as

- `onMove(RecyclerView, ViewHolder, ViewHolder)`
- `onSwiped(ViewHolder, int)`

Which allow you to implement drag and drop as well as swipe to dismiss without writing custom Behaviors or touch event handling.

Comment: That is a good blog, but it doesn't offer a solution to my problem. Coordinator layout is the root view and is intercepting my touches. And that was for Swiping and Dragging, and I have those working just fine. I need to solve Scrolling not being passed to the recyclerView.

Comment: Well no, you don't have it all working right: otherwise you wouldn't have a question here at all. You're going to have a lot, lot easier time stripping out the swipe/drag code you have with `ItemTouchHandler`, which does play nicely with `CoordinatorLayout` and nested scrolling.

Comment: Yeah, there is a question here because I don't have a problem with my swipe and drag. Like my question says, it was all working before I added the collapsing toolbar. The coordinator layout is intercepting the scroll before it to gets to the recyclerview. I don't think any changes could be made to the recycler view to change because the root view gets all touches first. It will have to be in the coordinator layout.

Comment: And yet, `ItemTouchHandler` 100% does work in a `CoordinatorLayout` and your code does not

Comment: Right, thus the question.

Comment: I implemented this just now, and I have the _same_ problem I did before. Which proves the problem lies in the coordinator layout, not the recycler view.

Comment: @ChadBingham have you had any luck with this? its a cordinator layout issue. My case when I scroll up sometimes my items get dismissed. If I do a diagonal swipe my items keep dismissing

Comment: @Mr.Noob No, I had no luck. I saw a bug reported on this issue. So I had to remove the coordinator layout until they fix it. I did see that an update just came out, so maybe the fix is in there. But I haven't check.

Comment: @ChadBingham thanks but it doesn't seem to be fixed in the latest yet either!